# APT-Pinning Kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, apt

My plan is, that my kernel is updated from the testing-repository of Debian. So that if I do a dist-upgrade, the kernel will be automatically upgraded.

My Problem is, that the dependencis aren't downloaded too.

How can I solve this?

sources.list contains additional the backport-repository and the testing one:

```
#Stable
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main non-free contrib
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free

#Testing
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main non-free contrib
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US testing/non-US main contrib non-free

#Unstable
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable main non-free contrib
deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US unstable/non-US main contrib non-free
```

my /etc/apt/preferences.d/mypref

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 650

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 600
```

my /etc/apt/preferences.d/kernel

```
Package: linux-image-amd64
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 950

Package: linux-headers-amd64
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 950
```

Comment: It is usually wiser to use the backport packages mixed with the stable release than the testing packages.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian